# How to retrieve data from php using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

Good day, I am new to AJAX. I'm trying to get a data from a function inside a class using a handler but when I include the class file the output becomes a bunch of html instead of the actual echoed string.

JS

```
$('#login-btn').on('click', function () {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    $.post("./php/functions/loginHandler.php",
        {
        usernameInput: username
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
});
```

```
PHP Handler
<?php
    include_once './php/database/DBOperations.php';
    if (isset($_POST['usernameInput'])) {
        echo 'test';
}
```

Thank you, have a good day.

Comment: The 'bunch of HTML' could well be an error message that's telling you what went wrong. What does it say?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular

```
 Warning: include_once(../fourRsResort/php/database/DBOperations.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\fourRsResort\php\functions\loginHandler.php on line <i>2</i></th></tr>
```

tried using absolute path but still getting errors

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths). That might help you identify the correct path for your `include` statement.

Answer (score -2):

Please use this ajax code, maybe working :

```js
$('#login-btn').on('click', function () {
      var username = $('#username').val();
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'your url',
            data: username,
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response)
           }
       });
});
```

warning : you must add jquery in your html file

Comment: Firstly, this is functionally identical to the OP's AJAX code, and secondly, the OP has posted the error message he's getting in the comments, and it's clearly about the PHP  `include`statement failing.